# Bundle with external react.js don't work — maybe some global variables are missing?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

May you please help me find roots of the problem?

I want to move react from bundle and load it from CDN, so I add to webpack config:

```
  externals: {
    react: {
      root: 'react',
      commonjs2: 'react',
      commonjs: 'react',
      amd: 'react',
      umd: 'react',
    },
    'react-dom': {
      root: 'ReactDOM',
      commonjs2: 'react-dom',
      commonjs: 'react-dom',
      amd: 'react-dom',
      umd: 'react-dom',
    },
  },
```

and to html:

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin></script>
<script async src="/client-2bb593ab57065d662f04.bundle.js"></script>
```

But in console i got:

```
Router.js:100 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Component' of undefined
    at eval (Router.js:100)
    at Object../node_modules/react-router/es/Router.js (client-2bb593ab57065d662f04.bundle.js:2713)
    at r (client-2bb593ab57065d662f04.bundle.js:1)
    at eval (MemoryRouter.js:10)
    at Object../node_modules/react-router/es/MemoryRouter.js (client-2bb593ab57065d662f04.bundle.js:2697)
    at r (client-2bb593ab57065d662f04.bundle.js:1)
    at eval (index.js:2)
    at Object../node_modules/react-router/es/index.js (client-2bb593ab57065d662f04.bundle.js:2725)
    at r (client-2bb593ab57065d662f04.bundle.js:1)
    at eval (index.jsx:15)
```

And I have no idea why, because I have simplified code and remove router at all.

Any ideas? With all my best Regards.

Answer (score 0):

To make it work i add `libraryTarget: 'umd'` to `output` of webpack config.
Was found here: https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/1275#issuecomment-246469528